# How to save Live and Historical Vehicle Location data in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, geohashing

I am trying to process and store location information of about 30k vehicles in DynamoDB.

- The Live information will be stored every 10 seconds for each vehicle.
- It will be processed to Live track single vehicle
- The info will also be used to get nearby vehicles given a point and radius.
- I will use python code

I am following following strategy:

**Hist table keeps device historical information**

- Data will be: deviceid (partition key), lat, lon, timestamp (sortkey), geohash

**Live table keeps live info**

- Data will be: deviceid (partition key), lat, lon, timestamp, geohash(sortkey)
- geo hash helps in searching nearby vehicles
- the table information will be updated such that only 30k data will present, one for each vehicle at a given time.

How can I improve on scaling of the Hist and Live table read and write given write is done every 10 seconds?

Comment: What scaling problems are you current experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the [Read and Write throughput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html) of DynamoDB tables upon creation and you can modify throughput later if necessary. In addition, DynamoDB allows [bursting beyond these defined throughput limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Bursting).

To obtain the full throughput of your tables, [use a wide range of Partition Keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload) so that requests are distributed to many different servers.

DynamoDB now [also supports Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb/), so it can **automatically scale** based upon usage.

For improved **scaling of eventually-consistent Reads**, you can also use [In-Memory Acceleration with DAX](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.html).

In situations of **bursty writes** (where there might be insufficient Write throughput), some AWS users use an Amazon SQS queue to temporarily store data after received a Throttling error, with a backend process that later reads these messages and inserts them into DynamoDB. This allows tables to be provisioned for *average* throughput rather than *peak* throughput.

**Bottom line:** You should be able to avoid most scaling issues by increasing the throughput of your tables. Other techniques (such as those detailed above) can provide even more scale.